# Is there any way to filter data of an html document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension that uses the html document of a website to extract data, but i need to make a filter to get what i exactly want.

In this attempt, the extension gets the HTML of the page and converts it into a string so it can be manipulated easily:

```
//This method gets a string and counts how many times
//the word you're looking for its in the string
function countWordInAString(string, word) {
    return (string.match(new RegExp(word, "g")) || []).length;
}

function getOutlookData(html) {
    var unreaded = countWordInAString(html, 'no leídos');
    var readed = countWordInAString(html, 'leídos');
    var totalMails = countWordInAString(html, 'id="AQAAA1thnTQBAAAEA7R1mgAAAAA="');
    var message = totalMails + 'Mails loaded! \n Mails readed: ' + readed + '\n Mails unreaded: ' + unreaded;

    return message + '\n' + "HTML:\n" + html;
}
```

It works in some specific cases, but for obfuscated websites (like outlook in this example), the results are erroneous. What i could do to improve it?

Comment: You are asking us to parse html we can't see. Nobody can do much to help without a [mcve]

Comment: The html that's being parsed it's the one from the page the chrome tab is loading, the extension get's it and then is converted to a string for a malleable use.

Comment: As the first comment says we need to see that problematic html but the problem is quite evident anyway: processing html to analyze its text won't work in general. You need to process `document.body.innerText` of the page. To analyze attributes you need to use DOM methods like querySelectorAll on the DOM, not on HTML. You can do it in the content script or you can reconstruct DOM in the background script by using DOMParser API.

Comment: Thanks man i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'word' may contain special characters.
When passing to your regex encode it with backslashes
ie

```
const encodeForReg = str => str.replace(/([^\s\w])/g, '\\$1');
function countWordInAString(string, word) {
    const encodedWord = encodeForReg(word);
    return (string.match(new RegExp(encodedWord, "g")) || []).length;
}
```

```
id="AQAAA1thnTQBAAAEA7R1mgAAAAA="
```

becomes

```
id\=\"AQAAA1thnTQBAAAEA7R1mgAAAAA\=\"
```